# ko.toJS() gets 'undefined' for variable initialized to ""

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I have a project in ASP.NET MVC 4 that uses knockoutjs to handle client-side stuff like keeping track of if a certain field has changed.

In the class declaration for my ViewModel, i have 2 observables, both initialized to `""`:

```
private _observables = {
        query: ko.observable(""),
        object: ko.observable("")
    }
```

In the `close` function of a dialog box, I check both observables using the isDirty() method to find out if they've changed, and prompt the user about saving if changes are detected.

I've stepped through and figured out that `object` doesn't appear to be tracked correctly, despite the line above. Inside isDirty(), knockout pulls the current state like this:

```
 target.isDirty = function () {
                var currentState = ko.toJS(target);
          ....logic
                returns dirty/notdirty
```

After the `ko.toJS()` call, the `object` field of `currentState` is always `undefined`, which causes it to fail the state check- because the initial state is properly recorded as `""`.

Even if I use `self._observables.object("")` to explicitly set `object` before the call to `isDirty()`, it's still `undefined` after the `ko.toJS()` call inside the 'dirty-checker'.

I thought the issue might be the binding in the view- it's bound to a hidden field that doesn't get user input, however as long as `object` is initialized, I don't see how that initial value is being lost/overwritten.

Comment: What do you see if you `console.debug(target)`? Does it include the _observables?

Comment: `isDirty()` is not a build in Knockout function. Please post which plugin/library do you use for the `isDirty()`!

Comment: Second previous comment. In addition, try to update the code in your question so that it's an actual repro (see "[mcve]" for guidance).

Comment: Apologies- you're right, I misunderstood where I stepped into during debugging. The ko.toJS() function does return `undefined` when I expect `""`, however I can't find toJS() defined anywhere in my knockout file- I'm using 3.1.0.

@Jeroen: what else would help with creating that minimal, complete, and verifiable example? I haven't been sure how to do that- obviously including every bit of code touched in this process would be huge, so I tried to keep it trimmed down

Comment: Have you read the page I linked (and its links)? It contains the answer to your question. Given the problem you describe I think it's very likely possible to create a short, *runnable* example that fully demonstrates the symptoms.

Comment: Put yourself in our shoes and re-read your question, because that's really *all* we have to go on: we can only resort to *guessing* what the problem is.

Comment: I see where you're coming from- part of the reason I felt OK leaving it short was that I thought this was happening directly inside a knockout file, and that I might be running into some sort of known issue. I see now that's not the case, so I'll try to get a runnable example up and link it here. Thanks